# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer una tabla HTML para comparar el valor de un input que contienen cada fila con el valor que ingrese por un input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5

Estoy haciendo una función que me permite agregar una fila con los datos de un articulo a una tabla html, esta fila se agrega cada vez que ingrese el ID de un articulo. Lo que quiero es que si ingreso un ID que ya existe en la tabla se incremente la cantidad de ese articulo en esa misma fila y no se vuelva a agregar otra fila con los datos de ese mismo articulo.

---

Esta función me permite agregar una fila con los datos de un articulo en la tabla html por cada ID que ingrese por un input

```
function listarventaporcodigo(idarticulo, nombre, precio_venta) {
let textoBusqueda = $("input#buscarporcodigo").val();
$.post("../ajax/venta.php?op=listarventaporcodigo", { idarticulo: textoBusqueda }, function (data) {
    let js = JSON.parse(data);
    //let contenedor = ""; 
    let fila = "";
    let cantidad = 1;
    let descuento = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < js.length; i++) {
        if (idarticulo != "") {
            let subtotal = cantidad * precio_venta;
            fila = '<tr class="filas" id="fila' + cont + '">' +
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle(' + cont + ')">X</button></td>' +
                '<td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" id="idarticulo" value="' + js[i].idarticulo + '">' + js[i].nombre + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="' + cantidad + '"></td>' +
                '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="' + js[i].precio_venta + '"></td>' +
                '<td><input type="number" name="descuento[]" value="' + descuento + '"></td>' +
                '<td><span name="subtotal" id="subtotal' + cont + '">' + subtotal + '</span></td>' +
                '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubototales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            cont++;
            detalles = detalles + 1;
            //modificarSubototales(); 
        } else {
            alert("error al ingresar el detalle, revisar los datos del artículo");
        }
        //estoy usando esta condicion para comparar pero solo funciona con un solo dato el primero que ingreso ya los demas no los valida 
        if ($('#idarticulo').val() == textoBusqueda) {
            for (let j = 1; j < cont; j++) {
                cantidad++;
                document.getElementById("cantidad[]").value = cantidad;
            }
        } else {
            $('#detalles').append(fila);
        }
    }
});
```

}

---

Esta es mi tabla HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                          <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
                                <th>Opciones</th>
                                <th>Artículo</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Precio Venta</th>
                                <th>Descuento</th>
                                <th>Subtotal</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <th style="font-size: 20px;">TOTAL</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th><h4 style="font-size: 30px;" id="total">$/. 0.00</h4><input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta"></th>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te preparo un ejemplo sencillo del que puedes partir.

En este caso, preparé una tabla con tres columnas:

- Id: Id del elemento
- Descripcion: La descripción la formo concatenando 'Item' + id
- Cantidad: Número de elementos añadidos con el mismo id.

Por otro lado, añadí un input y un botón. El input corresponderá al id y el botón será el que ejecute la acción de inserción en la tabla.

Con respecto al código del evento, está comentado y creo que se entiende. De cualquier manera lo explico a grandes rasgos:

1. Recorremos los `tr` de la tabla buscando una coincidencia en el id.
2. En caso de encontrar una coincidencia, sumamos uno al valor de la columna `Cantidad`.
3. En caso de no encontrar coincidencia, añadimos la fila a la tabla con el valor `Cantidad` = 1 por defecto.

```js
$('#add').click(function() {

  let 
    $tbody = $('#tbl > tbody'),
    id = $('#id').val(),
    updated = false;

  // Recorremos los tr de la tabla para buscar coincidencias
  $tbody.find('tr').each(function(i, val) {
    
    // En este caso, el id se encuentra en la posición 0. Deberás adaptarlo a tu caso si fuera necesario.
    if ($(val).find('td')[0].innerText == id) {

      // Igual que en el punto anterior, la cantidad se encuentra en la posición 2. Deberás adaptarlo en tu caso si fuera necesario.
      $(val).find('td')[2].innerText++;
      updated = true;
      return false;

    }
    
  }); 
  
  // La marca 'updated' indica si se actualizó la cantidad en el bucle anterior.
  // En caso de que no se actualizara, significa que no encontró el elemento por lo que lo añadimos.
  if (!updated)
    $tbody.append('<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>Item ' + id + '</td><td>1</td></tr>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- En el siguiente input se introducirá un valor entero que representará el id del elemento -->
    <input id="id" type="text" />
    <button id="add">Añadir</button>
    <br />
    <table id="tbl">
      <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono a la perfección justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución esta en ***Vainilla JS***.

Uso una función que recorre todas las filas de la tabla y los IDs de los artículos contenidos en las mismas para ver si ya existen, cada vez que se añade un nuevo artículo. Se desencadenan dos resultados: añadir una nueva fila o incrementar la cantidad en una fila existente.

Para simplificar en las filas de mi ejemplo solo añado la ID del articulo y la cantidad añadida para esa ID.

Un `input` de tipo numérico y un botón permiten añadir artículos a la tabla, en este ejemplo el artículo solo tiene una ID y se controla su cantidad según se van añadiendo IDs nuevas o preexistentes.
Un evento 'click' asociado al botón lanza la ejecución de la función principal `addTableItem()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <label for="item_id">Id artículo:</label>
            <input type="number" id="item_id">
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="add_item">
            Introducir artículo
        </button>
    </div>

    <h3>Tabla</h3>
    <table id="cart">
        <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--
                <tr data-id="">
                    <td class="id"></td>
                    <td class="amount">0</td>
                </tr>
            -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        const input = document.querySelector('input#item_id');
        const button = document.querySelector('button#add_item');
        button.addEventListener('click', function ()
        {
            if (input.value) {
                addTableItem(parseInt(input.value));
                input.value = '';
            }
        });

        function addTableItem(itemId) // void
        {
            let increasedAmount = false;

            const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
            const totalRows = rows.length;

            for (let index = 0; index < totalRows; index++) {
                const row = rows[index];

                const rowId = parseInt(row.dataset.id);

                console.log('Fila ID: ' + rowId + ' articulo ID: ' + itemId);
                if (rowId === itemId) { // without parseInt use == not ===
                    console.warn('INCREASE, ID: ' + itemId)
                    increaseRowAmount(row, 1);
                    increasedAmount = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Añado una fila cuando la tabla no tiene ninguna fila
            // o si el marcador increasedAmount mantiene su valor por defecto
            // (este se cambia si la ID ya existía y se incremento la cantidad)
            if (rows.length === 0 || !increasedAmount) {
                addNewRow(itemId);
            }
        }

        function addNewRow(itemId) // void
        {
            const trNode = getNewRow(itemId);
            const tableTbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
            tableTbody.appendChild(trNode);

            function getNewRow(itemId) // js node
            {
                const amountCell = document.createElement('td');
                const amountTextNode = document.createTextNode(1);
                const idCell = document.createElement('td');
                const idTextNode = document.createTextNode(itemId);

                amountCell.className = 'amount';
                amountCell.appendChild(amountTextNode);
                idCell.className = 'id';
                idCell.appendChild(idTextNode);

                const trNode = document.createElement('tr');
                trNode.appendChild(idCell);
                trNode.appendChild(amountCell);
                trNode.setAttribute('data-id', itemId);

                return trNode;
            }
        }
        function increaseRowAmount(trNode, amount = 1) // void
        {
            const cellNode = trNode.querySelector('td.amount');
            const newAmount = parseInt(cellNode.textContent) + amount;
            cellNode.innerText = newAmount;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Añadí un atributo `data-id` en la fila, es una forma más fácil de acceder a la ID, de otra forma tienes que obtener el contenido textual de la celda hija de la fila cada vez que tienes que comprobar la ID, esto es lo que hago para obtener la cantidad actual de filas preexistentes antes de incrementarla.